# resize image button

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have a button where I put a picture ... I must try to resize the image inside the button ... how can I resize it? Can I do it directly from the xml code?
This is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_root"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:background="@color/white_trasparent"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:textColor="@color/grey" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        </TextView>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Drawable Top" 
        android:id="@+id/Button03" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="10dp">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my understanding of the drawableTop/left/bottom/right properties is correct that is not going to place your image inside your button, rather it is going to put it on top (north of) your button.

If you're looking to put an image inside a button check out [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

I don't think either of these things will let you just set the size of only your image though (they will let you change the size of the whole view, in this case the rectangle button box, and the image inside it.)

In order to change the size of the image without affecting the size of the button box graphic I think you'd have to shrink your resource image in photoshop or something.